# Looking for a physical model for analog needle movements

Tags: java, android, game-physics

I'm building an Android application for a speedometer (or rpm) application.
The input signal (target value) will vary a lot and my current implementation is based on the ideas from [this Analog Speedometer example](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/)

However the regulation in this example is much to crude and gives a jerky/unnatural motion.
I'm looking for a physics model of the needle where speed and acceleration constants can be varied.
A model where you can feel the inertia of the needle, still with no overshoot.

Any help on this is appreciated. 
My own tries have not been very successful.

Thanks in advance